# iOS / Swift - Download image using AWS3 (Amazon SDK) asynchronously into a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Simple question: I have a struct that is a JSON fetched from server and I have a field called "imagePathFromAWS3", like this:

```
struct Card {
  let id: Int?
  let name: String?
  let imagePathFromAWS3: String?
}
```

Then, I want to present this information inside a CardCollectionView but I want to do that asynchronously because once the card is shown in the collection, I fetch the preview image from Amazon AWS3.

What is the best way to do that? Using AWSTask to create promises? Using Dispatches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use https://github.com/kean/Nuke for this. Works pretty well and will save you a lot of time.

Just pod it and use it like this:

```
nukeLoad(imgUrl: imagePathFromAWS3, into: cell.imageContainer)
```